# How to edit compiled ASP.net website?

Tags: asp.net

I have a website, published [here](http://wbs.ae/contactus.aspx).

On the contact us page, linked above, there is a drop down menu.

Depending on the selection of the content type in that menu, a different person is emailed.

The original developer, apparently to my inexperienced eyes at least, hardcoded the email addresses for those people.

Several of them have left the company, and we are maintaining their email addresses and checking them solely for the purpose of these web contacts.

Ideally, I would like to set up a control on the website admin page to allow the addresses to be edited in the future.

I can see and edit the contact us page in VS 2010 (currently using web matrix and VS 2010 Express but I have VS 2010 Professional as well.)

My experience is very limited, so I will have to learn a lot, I expect, to make this happen.

Enough background, I hope. What I need is to find where the emails are coded. The dropdown shows a identifier which relates to the selected choice, but I can't find what that relates to, or what control relates it to an email (or where it posts to when "Send" is clicked.)

I apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge. I'm trying to learn, and I have a job to do. I'll try not to suck up too much of anybody's time, and I'll try to work out on my own, what I can. Please let me know what further data I can provide.

This is the code for the dropdown. If there is a reference here to where the data I need is, I can't find it. I can post the rest of the code for the page if necessary.

EDIT: I posted the whole page. The dropdown seemed too basic to be of help.

**EDIT: Posted source code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Web.Mail;

public partial class ContactUs : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Calendar cal = new Calendar();
    string dat = cal.TodaysDate.Date.ToLongDateString();

        System.Web.Mail.MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
        mm.From = "WBS Website<info@wbs.ae>";
        if (DrpDwnType.SelectedItem.Value == "G")
            mm.To = "david@wbs.ae";
        else
            mm.To = "robert@wbs.ae";

        mm.Cc = "wolfi@wbs.ae";
        mm.Bcc = "precise.customer@gmail.com";
        mm.Subject = "Online comments from WBS website visitor, " + TXTFname.Text;
        mm.Body = "<div style='border:solid 2px RED; padding:25px 25px 25px 25px'><br><br> <strong>Online comments from WBS website</strong><br> <br> ------------------------------------- <br> Date : " + dat + "<br> <br> First Name : " + TXTFname.Text + "<br>Last Name : " + TXTLastName.Text + "<br> Email Address : " + TXTEmail.Text + "<br> Contact No : " + TXTMob.Text + "<br> Enquiry Type : " + DrpDwnType.SelectedItem.Text + "<br> <br> <br> The visitor comment : <br> --------------------------------------- <br> " + TXTComment.Text + "</strong><br><br>Further Information : " + RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() + "<br><br><br></div>";
        mm.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;
        SmtpMail.Send(mm);
        TXTFname.Text = "";
        TXTLastName.Text = "";
        TXTMob.Text = "";
        TXTComment.Text = "";
        TXTEmail.Text = "";
        TXTMess.Text = "Thank you for your interest in WBS!!! ";



}
```

}

Comment: could you post the code behind for this page, `.aspx.vb` or similar. Specifically the `Button1_Click` since there is no hardcoding in the markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the BIN folder of the website on the web server you will find one or more DLL files.

Those files can be "decompiled" to their source code using tools such as [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx).

After decompiling the whole code search for the keyword "DrpDwnType" and you should see where the email addresses are hard coded. After compiling it again you should be able to update the DLL files on the website to reflect the changes.

Comment: why would he have to do that? he said he has the source.

Comment: @f0x I think he got only the `.aspx` files, which are not the code behind.

Comment: perhaps - I have asked so lets see.

Comment: I have been told by the developer that I have all the source files. I don't have the experience to know if this is accurate. The developer has moved back to India, and is no longer responsive. If I understand correctly, there are 2 types of projects. One shold be fully compiled, and one is not. I do not have an .SLN file, and I'm assuming from that that I have a website project, which is not fully compiled. What should I look for, and where would I look for the source files if it is not a .sln file?

Comment: Do you have files with extension `.aspx.vb` or `.aspx.cs`? If so, those are the desired source files. Otherwise, you'll have to decompile the DLL(s) to get the true source files.

Comment: So I had the source files, on a disc, rather than in our external HDD backup. I have found the emails where they are hardcoded. To start with, I need to know what happens if I change them here. Do I build the project again? How do I deploy the new build? We've added pages and menu options manually on the deployed website, because it was the only way I could find to make any changes. Can I download those files to include in the new build, or do I need to redo them in the source? Again, thanks for your help, and thanks for putting up with my basic ignorance of what I'm doing.

Comment: You will have to recompile the code using Visual Studio to generate new DLL file.. when doing it you get one DLL or many?

Comment: There are many. I haven't recompiled it, but the original has many.

Comment: So I fear I got bad news.. you'll have to copy all the files - `*.aspx`, `*.ascx` and `*.dll` (to BIN folder) and do the changes to the `.aspx` all over again.. sorry!

Comment: So I need to copy all of the files from the published folder to the BIN folder in the VS2010 site, and redo the changes to the .aspx that I made on the published site?

Comment: You need to overwrite the existing files on the live server, yes.. the `.aspx` and `.ascx` sit in the root (usually) and only the `.dll` in the BIN folder.

Comment: That isn't possible in our situation. I need to recreate the site, and upload to an alternative server for testing before I can overwrite the live site.

Comment: OK. Sounds good.. can't really help you with that though unless you have question?

Comment: I understand. I think that what I need to do is import the original site into Visual Studio, recreate my server side .aspx changes there, and then rebuild the website. That should allow me to publish to a testing server, include my changes, and not overwrite the original site until I know this one works. Make sense?

Comment: If you're available, I'd like to chat more directly. You up to that? zenbike@gmail.com

Answer (score 3):

Seriously, the best advice I can give you is to contract a new developer to help you out.

What happens when the production system stops working because it was not tested or deployed properly? Its likely no one here can help you then because they cannot see all the details of your system's configuration, and you'll find yourself under even more time pressure to solve the new problem, with users getting upset with you.

Comment: I understand, and I appreciate that. I don't currently have the option to hire a developer. Most of the site is essentially static pages, and the one form I have an issue with is not critical, should it fail. Nonetheless, I intend to test as best I can by deploying the site on an alternative webhost and url, and I have a full backup of the site, so worst case, I can revert to my current starting position within a few minutes time. I realize this is outside my level of expertise. We are located in the Middle East, and have been unable to find a reliable developer.